# Beamer: how to load professionalfonts font theme?

Tags: beamer, luatex, math-fonts

Both following preamble codes give the same output of typesetting math in `serif` font.

Is there a technical difference between two ways that doesn't show up here?

**1st approach**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

**2nd approach**

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
```

### Complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,bm}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\newcommand\vm[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand\pbm[1]{\left(\mathbf{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        some text
        \begin{align}
        \vm{\Phi}_{,\gamma}^T & = \vm{P}_{,\gamma}^T\pbm{x}\,\vm{A}^{-1}\,\vm{B} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c c c c}
        \phi_1 & \phi_2 & \cdots & \phi_n 
        \end{array} \right\}_{\left(1 \times n\right)},\\
        %
        \mathbf{\widetilde{T}_s} & =%
        \left\{%
        \begin{array}{ccccc}
        T_1 & T_2 & \cdots & T_n & \bm{0}_{\left( 1 \times m \right)} 
        \end{array}%
        \right\}^T
        \end{align}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read your `.log` when using the class option `professionalfont` you'll see

```
Class beamer Warning: ``professionalfont'' is obsolete.
Use font theme ``professionalfonts'' instead on input line ...
```

*i.e.* the option is deprecated, and as such may be removed at some stage. At the implementation level the two are the same.

Comment: Many thanks. I already searched for `professionalfont` in the beamer manual, but maybe I overlooked this piece of information.

Comment: If you don't mind, I have another question. Does this command `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` implicitly make math font `serif`? because the default theme math font is not `serif` and was changed when loading this command.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou The professional font set up simply leaves math mode fonts alone, so you get the LaTeX standard set up

Comment: I am grateful for your clarification.